# Cache vs storing "similar" results in database

Tags: php, laravel, performance, caching, search

I am in the processing of developing a video sharing site, on the video page I was displaying "similar videos" using just a database query (based on tags/category) I haven't run into any problems with this, but I was debating basically running using my custom search function to match similar videos even more closely (so its not only based on similar categories, but tags, similar words, etc..) however my fear is running this on every video view would be too much (in terms of resources, and just not being worth it since its not a major part of the site)

So I was debating doing that - but storing results (maybe store 50 and pull 6 from that 50 by id) - I can update them maybe once a week or whenever, (again since its not a major part of the site, i don't need live searching), but my question is.... is there any down or upside to this?

I'm looking specifically at cacheing the similar video results or simply saying "never mind it" and keep it based on tags. Does anyone have any experience/knowledge on how sites deal with offering similar options for something like this?

(I'm using php, mysql, built using laravel framework, search is custom class built on the back of laravel scout)

Answer (score 0):

Every decision you make as a developer is a tradeoff. If you cache results, you get speed on display, but get more complexity during cache management (and probably bugs). You should decide is it worth it, as we do not know your page load time requirements (or other KPI), user load, hardware and etc.

But in general i would cache this data.